# Optimal and best way to control Recycler View items

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview

what could be the best way to control events in RecyclerView items? That is, if we are going to change the display of the Recycler View items, or if we are going to test an event on them at all, what would be the **best way**?

I mean, to control these changes on each item in the **onBindViewHolder()** method, or in the **MyViewHolder class**, if the latter is more appropriate, then how do we calculate the first position?
Because **Default -1** comes first and this issue causes it to crash sometimes.

**Thank you** if you have a better experience in this field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform the event automatically (not from user behaviour), then you must do it within `onBindViewHolder()`.

If you want to perform an event based on the user behaviour (like click, drag, etc.), then you can do it within the `onBindViewHolder()` or `MyViewHolder`.